# Having trouble redirecting in Rails if my user has a certain role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, roles

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I want to assign roles to my users so I have this in my app/model/users.rb file …

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, through: :assignments

  def role?(role)
    roles.any? { |r| r.name.underscore.to_sym == role }
  end

  def admin?
    role? "Admin"
  end
end
```

but when I log in with the only user in my system, I’m not redirected to the admin page (instead the “else” clause of the below is executed …

```
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    if user.admin?
      render 'admin/index'
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

I can’t figure out why this is.  Below is the only data currently in my PostGres database …

```
myproject=> select * FROM Assignments;
 id | user_id | role_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+---------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  4 |       8 |       1 | 2016-05-10 21:15:01.863456 | 2016-05-10 21:15:01.863456
(1 row)

myproject=> select * FROM users;
 id |   provider    |          uid          |     name      | oauth_token | oauth_expires_at |         created_at         |         updated_at         |          email          
----+---------------+-----------------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------
  8 | google_oauth2 | 177611649021871409999 | Dave A        |             |                  | 2016-05-10 21:15:01.861259 | 2016-05-10 21:15:01.861259 | myemail@gmail.com
(1 row)

myproject=> select * FROM roles;
 id | name  |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+-------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | Admin | 2016-04-28 19:55:43.473016 | 2016-04-28 19:55:43.473016
  2 | User  | 2016-04-28 19:55:43.492222 | 2016-04-28 19:55:43.492222
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string "Admin" to `role?` but in the block being passed to `roles.any?` you are matching on a symbol. This should work:

```
def role?(role)
  roles.any? { |r| r.name.underscore.to_sym == role.to_s.underscore.to_sym }
end
```

with this you can pass `"Admin"`, `"admin"`, or `:admin` to `role?`